# WPF Make ScrollViewer transparent

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I would like to get scrollbar in ListBox see through.
Currently I managed to move contents under with negative margin, but I cannot make it visible under ScrollBar even setting its Opacity.

Any ideas?

[image]

Current XAML (to disable selection and hover effects):

```
            <ListBox x:Name="TestIC" Grid.Row="1"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">100</sys:Double>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-100,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must simply override the default `Style` of the `ScrollViewer` and e.g., place it in the `ResourceDictionary` of *App.xaml* or your `ListBox`:

- Allow the content to stretch into the scroll bar's column/row by setting the `ColumnSpan`/`RowSpan` of the `ScrollContentPresenter`
- Set `Background` of `ScrollBar` elements, and if required the `Rectangle` named `"Corner"` too, to `Transparent` or modify their `Opacity`

To make the `Thumb` of the `ScrollBar` opac, override/copy all the default [ScrollBar Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollbar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and set the `Thumb.Opacity` in the `x:Key="ScrollBarThumb"` style.
As you already have a customized `ScrollBar`, you probably want to adjust your current `Thumb` style instead.

Important: don't forget to remove your negative `Margin`!
Since the content of the `ScrollViewer` is now allowed to span accross the full content host, the `Margin` is no longer needed. You should generally avoid a negative `Margin` in order to layout elements, when arranging them in columns (using proper spanning) yield the same result.

```xml
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
      
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
          </Border>
          <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                     Grid.Column="1"                         
                     Background="Transparent"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
          <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                     Grid.Row="1" 
                     Background="Transparent"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

          <Rectangle x:Name="Corner"
                     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                     Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Great and working answer. Thanks!